# Android HTTP post request on clicking button

Tags: java, android, https, request

i want to send an HTTP post request by Clicking on Button to my website. i searched allot only found this piece of code

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

But i don't know how it work with an clicking on button.

Comment: Complete code? I think you should ask for pointers. Do you know how to call a method on click of a button? If not you should read Android documentation. If you know how to do that you have my hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for Performing Network Opertion on Button Click  as:

```
public class onbuttonclickHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        byte[] result = null;
        String str = "";
       // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

        try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
                str = new String(result, "UTF-8");
            }
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }  
        return str;
    }

    /**
     * on getting result
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // something with data retrieved from server in doInBackground
    }
}
```

and on Button Click Start AsyncTask onbuttonclickHttpPost as:

```
buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
         public void onClick(View v) {
         new onbuttonclickHttpPost.execute(null);

     }
      });
```

Comment: Imran i did same, infect i copied your code into my project but it will ask to change type of  protected String doInBackground(String... params) into Void.

Comment: Great answer! My question is this still relevant? I.e. are people firing HTTP request/response on button click? The reason I ask is this was posted in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...its from my working project

I have used `Thread` and `NameValuePair` to execute this.....

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {

        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;

                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }

                    Log.d("Check Now", sb + "");

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } /*
                 * catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { // TODO
                 * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch
                 * (SAXException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method " + sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```