# android secure comment to web posts

Tags: android, http-post

I found how to make http post on android from this answer on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899938

I don't know if this is a good idea for making http posts, because it's not secure, anyone who knows the url to make comments on my post, can post spam with the url.

So, how can I make a secure comment box for my app?

Comment: Your question is rather open-ended, you will more likely receive help if you can narrow down to exactly what part of the comment box is causing you difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand what POST means.  The other question was asking how to send data to an HTTP server using a method called POST-  every request to an HTTP server has a method, such as POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, etc.  He was not asking about posting data to a comment app.  You can do that via HTTP POST, but you need to send authenticating information, use HTTPS for security, and provide all the authentication in the web service on the other end.  What he was asking was only a portion of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What a post method does:

> The POST Method
>
> Note that query strings (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request:
>
> ```
> POST /test/demo_form.asp HTTP/1.1
> Host: w3schools.com
> name1=value1&name2=value2
> ```
>
> Some other notes on POST requests:
>
> 1. POST requests are never cached
> 2. POST requests do not remain in the browser history
> 3. POST requests cannot be bookmarked
> 4. POST requests have no restrictions on data length

For your concern:

> anyone who knows the url to make comments on my post, can post spam with the url.

In POST method, data is not displayed in the URL. That means the person who is viewing or using the URL will not get to know what data is being sent with the URL. It will only show up when the user uses GET or query string with URL.

For more information, you can [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).