# Trigger HTTP request on button click

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask

I am trying to trigger a HTTP post request on each button click to get some data from a webservice in android. I have created an async task to send the http request. My code is as follows :

Activity

```
public void sendHttpRequest(View view){
    //gets called on button click
    new MyHttpRequestTask(this).execute();
}
```

MyHttpRequestTask

```
public class MyHttpRequestTaskextends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Show received data 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //Send http request
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am having two problems, one is that the onPostExecute method is not being fired and the other is, if I press the button second time or multiple times, the task is not being executed. But somehow I think that onPostExecute method not being called is the reason for the task not being executed on second time. So, what am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of these issues? Thanks

Here is the full doInBackground method

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Looper.prepare();
    GpsHelper gpsHelper = new GpsHelper();
    LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper(mContext);
    gpsHelper.turnGPSOn();
    String location = locationHelper.getMyCurrentLocation();
    ...
    String rawHtml = HttpHelper.sendPostRequest(postUrl, postParams);
    HtmlHelper.processRawHtml(rawHtml);
    Looper.loop();
    return null;
}
```

It gets the current location using GPS, then the current address and posts them to a webservice, then the response from webservice is parsed and processed. Is the problem due to the GPS ?

Comment: don't see a reason why onpostexecute is not getting called. post more details please.

Comment: where the request code inside in your doInBack...

Comment: Please follow this code. It works very well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899793/android-http-post-request-on-clicking-button

Answer (score 0):

Here you should call your method like

```
public MyHttpRequestTask myHttpRequestTask;

     public void sendHttpRequest(View view){
            //gets called on button click

        //Status.PENDING -- got the status when your asynch task not run yet with same instance
        //Status.RUNNING -- whether it running


            if(myHttpRequestTask.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED || myHttpRequestTask.getStatus() ==       Status.PENDING){

                  myHttpRequestTask = new MyHttpRequestTask(this).execute();
              }


        }
```

if your asynch task is in running task then no need to start it again and it would not be start.

it would be feasible if you create a new object when your status of asynchtask is either finish or pending. and please put the log or system out in your post method so you can easily identify it whether it will be called. please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Please do this in your code,

```
public void sendHttpRequest(View view){
//gets called on button click
new MyHttpRequestTask().execute();
}

public class MyHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //Send http request
    return null;
}


@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //please put your code here. 


    }
}
```

try this code, and if any issues then please mention here.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of head banging and debugging, I finally figured it out.
The onPostExecute was not being executed because of the GPS codes. Apparently, starting gps started few threads which were not terminated and hence onPostExecute was not being executed.